# How to open multiple directories and read the files inside

Tags: python, directory

I need to compare text files with two other files, and then get the result as an output. So I taught myself enough to write the following script which works fine and compares all of the files in a specific directory, however I have multiple directories with text files inside. What I need is to compare all of the text files in all of the directories and have an output file for each directory. Is there a way to improve the code below to do that:

```
import glob
import os
import sys

sys.stdout = open("citation.txt", "w")
for filename in glob.glob('journal*.txt'):
    f1 = open(filename,'r')
    f1data = f1.readlines()

    f2 = open('chem.txt')
    f2data = f2.readlines()

    f3 = open('bio.txt')
    f3data = f3.readlines()


    chem = 0
    bio = 0
    total = 0
    for line1 in f1data:
        i = 0
        for line2 in f2data:
            if line1 in line2:
                i+=1
                total+=1
                chem+=1
        if i > 0:
            print 'chem ' + line1 + "\n"
        for line3 in f3data:
            if line1 in line3:
                i+=1
                total+=1
                bio+=1
        if i > 0:
            print 'bio ' + line1 + "\n"


    print filename
    print total 
    print 'bio ' + str(bio) 
    print 'chem ' + str(kimya)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a list of directories and a  for loop

```
directories = ['folder1','folder2',...]
for i,folder in enumerate(directories):
    sys.stdout = open("citation{}.txt".format(i), "w")

    ...
    [put the rest of your code here]
```

This will name different output files as `citation0.txt` but you can do other formats if you want, just by changing how that name is declared.

And if you want each `citation.txt` to go into the actual directory, just change your code to this:

```
for folder in directories:
    citation = os.path.join(folder, "citation.txt")
    sys.stdout = open(citation, "w")
```

This will create a path for a new `citation.txt` file with each directory as the loop runs. Make sure to `import os` at the start of your file, if you haven't already.

Comment: This helped a lot, but I was also wondering if it is possible to create an output file for each directory I compare. Other than that, it works great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The way I set up `i` and `enumerate` with `sys.stdout = open("citation{}.txt".format(i), "w")` should do that, though they'll all be saved into the same folder. Do you mean you'd like them to go into each separate directory?

Comment: Exactly, would this be possible?

Comment: Yeah, I'll add it into my answer.

Comment: I changed the code but it gives this error: No such file or directory: 'folder1/citation.txt' How can I fix that?

Comment: You'll need to change the variables in the `directories` list to match the paths of your folders.

Comment: Yes, I changed them to the pathnames. I should've been more clear. The error is `No such file or directory: 'EPJA TR/citation.txt'` and EPJA TR is the first folder.

Comment: Ah I see. You may need to use absolute instead of relative paths. The loop might inadvertently change which directory python is operating in by the time you move onto a new iteration.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but after looking at the saved files, I saw that instead of reading the files in the different directories, it just reads the files in the directory the code is in. I tried to use `os.path.join(folder)` to read the files in the for loop, however Python doesn't allow me to use a list. How can I sort this out? I want it to perform the same task for every file in each directory one by one.

Comment: Hm, what's the actual error code it's giving? Are you trying to do `os.path.join` with `folder` or `folders`?

Comment: This is error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'` and this is the code `for folder in directories:
 f1 = open(os.path.join(folder, glob.glob('journal*.txt'),'r'))`

Comment: `glob.glob` returns a list, so you should still be using `for filename in glob` and just passing the joined path into glob. Like this: `for folder in directories: for file in glob.glob(os.path.join('journal*.txt'))`